# Network connection drops on Ubuntu 18.04 when using a Robot Operating System (ROS) setup

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet

I have a robot with the follow setup and the ethernet interface (enp4s0) of [Computer A] drops randomly.

The interface does not drop when the computers are not doing much. However when [Computer B] starts streaming a compressed image stream to [My Computer] via [Computer A], the ethernet interface drops.

Hence it seems like it is a configuration problem where I am possibly flooding the network unintentionally, which causes the network connection to drop, and I would like to get some advice regarding this matter.

Output from dmesg wasn't really helpful

dmesg from Computer A

```
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:33 2021] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:33 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered disabled state
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:35 2021] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:35 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered blocking state
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:35 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered listening state
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:39 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered learning state
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:44 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered forwarding state
[Mon Apr 12 13:43:44 2021] br0: topology change detected, propagating
[Mon Apr 12 14:05:50 2021] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Down
[Mon Apr 12 14:05:50 2021] br0: port 1(enp4s0) entered disabled state
[Mon Apr 12 14:05:52 2021] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

Things I have already done:

1. Checked and replaced all the ethernet cables with new ones.
2. Swap out the all the computers and sensors with spares
3. Enable STP on the network bridge with forward delay of 4

Unfortunately I am unable to connect everything to the switch due to the size constraints within the robot.

#### Setup

[image: SBC Setup]

All the computers are running Ubuntu 18.04 and [ROS Melodic Morenia](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic).

I have setup a network bridge using netplan as shown below

```
# Netplan on Computer A
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    #Computer B
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
    #Sensor 
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
    #SBC to switch
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      

  #Setup a bridge and link eno1 to it
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp1s0, enp2s0, enp4s0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.253
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      dhcp4: no
```

#### Other things I have tried:

Enable Port forwarding & add a route from [Computer B] to [Computer A] and setting up the NICs on different subnet in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Computer B

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1

# Netplan on Computer A
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    #Computer B
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.1/24
      dhcp4: no
    #Sensor 
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.3.1/24
      dhcp4: no
    #SBC to switch
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 192.168.1.253      
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that eno1 and enp4s0 are using different drivers. So I tried switching both interface and now the interface does not drop. Might be an outdated driver that is causing the drop.

```
sudo lspci -v
```

Interface eno1

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM (rev 30)                                                                                                                      
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (6) I219-LM                                                                                                                                         
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141                                                                                                                                                   
Memory at a1a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]                                                                                                                                            
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3                                                                                                                                                        
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+                                                                                                                                           
Kernel driver in use: e1000e                                                                                                                                                                         
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Interface enp4s0

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at a1780000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=32]
Memory at a1800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Expansion ROM at a1700000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number c4-00-ad-ff-ff-4c-52-bf
Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
Kernel driver in use: igb
Kernel modules: igb
```

Current netplan on computer A

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.3.1/24
      dhcp4: no
    enp1s0:
      mtu: 1500
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.1/24
      dhcp4: no
    eno1:
      mtu: 1500
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.253
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8]
    enp4s0:
      mtu: 1500
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.253
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8]
```